# Migration to Angular, Model was resolved to but '--alowJs' is not set

Tags: angular

After migrating Angular from 2.4.6 to 4.1 by using the [migration guide](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-1.0-update)
I get a few errors, most of them I fixed myself but I can't seem to find a fix for this one.

I import  string-to-json like this `import * as str2json from '../../../../node_modules/string-to-json/lib/string-to-json.js';` in translateLoader.ts

And get this error:

```
ERROR in C:/development/projects-git/mydoc/static-web/src/app/cross-  
cutting/translation/translateLoader.ts (4,27): Module 
'../../../../node_modules/string-to-json/lib/string-to-json.js' was resolved 
to 'C:/development/projects-git/mydoc/static-web/node_modules/string-to-
json/lib/string-to-json.js', but '--allowJs' is not set.
```

I added `"allowJs" : true,` to the `compilerOptions` in my `tsconfig.json` but that changed nothing.

The next error is `ERROR in AppModule is not an NgModule`.

npm and node versions:

```
npm: '4.5.0'
node: '6.10.1'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also add `"allowJs" : true` to `tsconfig.app.json`, not only the root `tsconfig.json`.